# Como achar a posição de um item numa lista?

Tags: python, algoritmo, lista

Estou escrevendo uma programa que recebe uma quantidade específica de valores, e retorna o menor valor da lista e sua posição. Está da seguinte forma:

```
quantidade = int(raw_input())
numeros = raw_input()
NumerosNaLista = numeros.split()
if len(NumerosNaLista) == quantidade:
    MenorValor = min(NumerosNaLista)
    print "Menor valor:", MenorValor
```

Tentei usar `find`para encontrar a posição do menor valor em `NumerosNaLista`, mas não funciona. Como proceder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#*-* coding: utf-8 *-*

numbers = raw_input()

# gera um vetor de numeros atravez da string
n_list = [ int(x) for x in numbers.split() ]

n_min = min(n_list)
n_pos = n_list.index(n_min) # pega a posição do valor n_min

print "Menor valor: %s" % n_min
print "Posição: %" % n_pos
```

Comment: Entendo. Eu preciso submeter meu código a um site, que só aceita se estiver correto, ou seja, se funcionar. Escrevi dois códigos que funcionam, mas ele não aceita, e aparentemente quer que eu escreva utilizando loops que vão substituindo os menores valores encontrados e guardando sua posição. Vou colocar o segundo código, gostaria que desse uma olhada.

Comment: @GuilhermeSantanaDeSouza, entendi, é um daqueles sites de maratonas de programação, tem uns exercicios bem chatos.

Comment: Na verdade é um site usados pelos professores... Eles cadastram os problemas, e os alunos tem que resolver e enviar... Quem não envia, fica sem presença... Apesar de alguns erros, meus dois códigos atendem ao que o problema pede, e o site não aceitou... Obrigado pelos toques.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode implementar seu algoritmo utilizando loop, neste caso o `while`. Veja como ficou este exemplo:

```
lista = []
i = 0
quantidade = int(raw_input('Qtd: '))

while (i < quantidade):
    numero = input("Valor: ")
    i += 1
    lista.append(numero)

print 'Indice do menor valor:', lista.index(min(lista))
```

Entrada (quantidade de números a ser inserido na lista):

> 3

Entrada (valores):

> 21
>   33
>   -21

Saída (índice do menor valor):

> 2

O método `index()` encontro o índice de um item de uma determinada lista, passado o item desejado como argumento que neste caso foi o menor valor da lista retornado pelo método `min()`.

Sugiro consultar a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) para aprender mais a respeito dos métodos e uma leitura sobre [manipulação de listas em Python](https://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/brincando-com-listas/).

Answer (score 2):

Tá bem antiga a postagem, mas a resposta pode servir para os próximos. Para retornar o índice de um elemento de uma lista você deve usar `index(elemento)`.

```py
lista = ["a", "b", "c"] 
print(lista.index("b")) # Retorna: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui da seguinte maneira:

```
quantidade = int(raw_input())
numeros = raw_input()
NumerosNaLista = numeros.split()
if len(NumerosNaLista) == quantidade:
    MenorValor = min(NumerosNaLista)
    print "Menor valor:", MenorValor
    lista = numeros.replace(" ", "")
    MenorValor = min(lista)
    posicao = lista.find(MenorValor)
    print "Posicao:", posicao
```

Funcionou, e acredito que esteja certo. Se houver algum erro, peço que seja informado por quem visualizar.

Comment: tem algumas linhas redundantes no seu código, como a `quantidade`, como não tem nenhuma estrutura de repetição não é necessário, a condição `if`, e o jeito que você está pegando a posição não é o jeito mais viável, o correto é usar o vetor já existente, vou deixar um exemplo na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma:

```
menor_ate_agora = None
quantidade = int(raw_input())
numeros = raw_input()
NumerosNaLista = numeros.split()
if len(NumerosNaLista) == quantidade:
    for valor in NumerosNaLista:
        if menor_ate_agora is None:
            menor_ate_agora = valor
        elif valor < menor_ate_agora:
            menor_ate_agora = valor
    print "Menor valor:", menor_ate_agora
    lista = numeros.replace(" ", "")
    MenorValor = min(lista)
    posicao = lista.find(MenorValor)
    print "Posicao:", posicao
```

Answer (score -1):

Simples assim...

```
print('Posição: {}'.format(NumerosNaLista.index(MenorValor))
```